# Audio delay of 0.25, i'm not sure which part is wrong

Tags: verilog, delay

```
module my_delay_mod(
    input [11:0]audio,
    input delay_clk,
    output [11:0]delay_out
    );

    integer i;
    reg [11:0]memory[0:4999];

    always @ (posedge delay_clk) begin 

        memory[0]<=audio;
        for (i=0; i<4999; i=i+1) begin
            memory[i+1]<=memory[i];
        end

    end 

    assign delay_out = memory[4999];

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be hard to synthesis. If you want a synthesisable code, I suggest that, you use a RAM based shift register. You can either use the IP's available with the vendor(I know Xilinx have one in Coregen) or make your own(not so complicated).

In a RAM based shift register you don't really shift all the data in every clock cycle. But you have different read and write pointers. The values of these pointers are separated by the delay value(in terms of number of clock cycles).

the steps would be,

1. create a RAM with **delay+2** depth.
2. keep writing to RAM in every clock cycle and increment the address.
3. when the write address is equal to **delay**, keep reading the data from address 0 onward. From now on, the read and write will happen in every clock cycle.
4. Whenever the end of RAM is reached the write or read addresses are reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your delay_clk is 20Khz, which is the same sampling rate of your mic_i**N**, yo**U** may try the code**S** below.

```
integer ee;
reg [11:0] memory[0:2020];

always @ (posedge delay_clk) begin 

    memory[0]<=audio;
    for (ee = 0; ee < 2020; ee = ee+1) begin
        memory[ee+1]<=memory[ee];
    end

    delay_out <= memory[2020];
end
```

This is some sample codes that may help you but the values may be incorrect. This should point you in the correct direction.